# FusionTable API Query LIKE operator and wildcards

Tags: google-fusion-tables

When i use wildcards based on the [LIKE documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_%28SQL%29#LIKE) linked from [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference) the query does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE country LIKE 'Cana%'
```

finds no matches and returns a Bad Request 400.  It works when i replace 'Cana%' with 'Canada', returning all records containing 'Canada'.

- How can i write the query to work with wildcards?
- Does LIKE work with Regular Expressions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be important to know, how you send the request.

The % is used for encoding inside URLs , try to use `%25` instead of `%` .
( `%25` is the url-encoded percent-sign)

Example:( [Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1GVGnBtjVXdwvVjLNVwbP_Pzy_I6rbqu0gv5njBM) )

`SELECT Kilograms FROM 1GVGnBtjVXdwvVjLNVwbP_Pzy_I6rbqu0gv5njBM where Country LIKE 'Can%25'`

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't work for me.
I use following code :

```
function changeMap() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value.replace("'", "\\'");
  layer.setQuery("SELECT 'lat' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'nameloc' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'");
  return false;
}
```

OK, when you use the numeric tableid, but not with the encripted tableid!
(LIKE or MATCHES instead of CONTAINS IGNORING CASE makes no difference).